# What changes would a simple Process State Diagram need for a dual-core system?

Tags: process, operating-system, state, cpu, processor

I have an exam question I am revising for where I cannot find a concrete answer.

The question is "For the simple process state diagram shown, what changes would need to be incorporated for an OS running on a dual-core system? Explain."

[Here is the diagram in question linked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK5MV.png)

[I have found a similar question asked on this site but I believe they asked about it incorrectly (they asked how it would work on a Linux system) rather than 'simple' example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43844228/process-states-on-a-single-processor-vs-dual-core-system)

I've also tried researching to find this information in books such as Silberchatz's Operating System Concepts but to no avail.

Anyways, my understanding of this is that each core would have their own process in the running state therefore allowing two instead of one. However, if this was the case, does this mean that I would need to add an extra running state to the diagram? I was under the impression that the other states wouldn't need to be changed as the processes would be stored in main memory anyways.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer to this question is entirely system specific.  That said, in a system that supports threads, threads have states; not processes. The state diagram for a thread is the same as for a process.

Comment: You're correct. This answer didn't require a concrete answer and is essentially what you said.